# Java Find duplicate lat/long for a List<LatLongObject> and keep the count for each entry

Tags: java, collections

I have a scenario wherein i have a List and i have to find the duplicate entries (the duplicate lat/long) in this and store the count for each entry.

So lets say i have 6 enrties here

```
LatLongObject1  -- >  "lat": 30.54203,"lon": -87.845879
LatLongObject2  -- >  "lat": 31.54203,"lon": -86.845879
LatLongObject3  -- >  "lat": 32.54203,"lon": -88.845879
LatLongObject4  -- >  "lat": 33.54203,"lon": -89.845879
LatLongObject5  -- >  "lat": 34.54203,"lon": -85.845879
LatLongObject6  -- >  "lat": 30.54203,"lon": -87.845879
```

So i can get something like:

```
LatLongObject1  -- >  Count 2
LatLongObject2  -- >  Count 1
LatLongObject3  -- >  Count 1
LatLongObject4  -- >  Count 1
LatLongObject5  -- >  Count 1
LatLongObject6  -- >  Count 2
```

I know this can be achieved using two for loops but i dont want to do that as the time complexity would be too high. Any better suggestions please.

Comment: So you definitely have a `List` to start with, and not a `Map`?  In that case, how are you distinguishing between `LatLongObject1` and `LatLongObject6`?  To me it seems that they are indistinguishable at this point (being, as they are, equal).  If that's true it simplifies things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map<LatLongObject1, Integer>` instead of `list` and update value for each key you find.